# Executing 3 asynchronous operations (where the 2nd one depends of a condition)

Tags: breeze, durandal

I am working on a **durandal / breeze** project.

I need to perform several things in my activate function. Thanks to `promises` I am able to chain asynchronous operations. Please note that I'm still a beginner with all these things so don't hesitate to correct my code.

I have the following activate function inside my viewModel:

```
var activate = function (routeData) {

    initLookups()

    var idTran = parseInt(routeData.idTran);
    var idItin = parseInt(routeData.idItin);

    return datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport)
            .then(function () { return datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary); });
}
```

**So in the return statement:**

1. I fill the `transport` observable thanks to `getTransportById`
2. *then* I fill the `itinerary` observable thanks to `getItineraryById`

-

So far so good. This code works and do his job as expected (maybe not optimised). Now I need to insert a condition between these 2 operations for the case of creating a new entity (if idItin==-1). In this case, a new entity is created. I try with the code below but it doesn't work: I mean the `promise` doesn't seems to do his job here and thus the view is displayed without waiting for the asynchronous operations to complete.

```
var activate = function (routeData) {

    initLookups()

    var idTran = parseInt(routeData.idTran);
    var idItin = parseInt(routeData.idItin);

    return datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport)
            .then(function () { if (idItin == -1) return datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran); })
            .then(function () { return datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary); });
}
```

And below is the `createItineraryDetailTransport` function of the datacontext:

```
var createItineraryDetailTransport = function (idTransport) {

    var initialValues = ({
        transportId: idTransport
    });

    var newItinerary = manager.createEntity(entityNames.itinerary, initialValues);
    return manager.addEntity(newItinerary);
}
```

So does someone have an idea how to code this thing?

Comment: Are you sure there's not something else going on?  Your code seems right to me.  Does this fiddle demonstrate what you're trying to do?  http://jsfiddle.net/bEfrS/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the rigth way is:

```
return datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport).then(function () {
    return datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary).then(function(){
        if (idItin == -1) return datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran);
        //You have to return something different tu null,false,undefined... or a promise
        return true; 
    );
});
```

Also, if there is not needed to do this calls sequently, you can do in parallel using Q library (https://github.com/kriskowal/q). The solution could be:

```
if(idItin ==-1){
    //CreateItineraryDetailTransport don't return a promise.
    //You can call that like a normal methond.
    //It is not a asyncronous methond
    datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran);
}
return Q.all([datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport),datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary)]);
```

-----EDIT-----

Solution doing the creation between the two other calls:

```
   return datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport).then(function () {
        if (idItin == -1) return datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran).then(function(){
            return datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary);
        });
        return datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary)
    });

   // I am using Q to do this method return a promise
    var createItineraryDetailTransport = function (idTransport) {

        var deferred = Q.defer();

        var initialValues = ({
            transportId: idTransport
        });

        var newItinerary = manager.createEntity(entityNames.itinerary, initialValues);
        manager.addEntity(newItinerary);

        deferred.resolve(true);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Also you can use Q.fcall:

```
return Q.fcall(function(){ datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran);};
```

I think that maybe, you don't need to do createItineraryDetailTransport return a promise. Maybe this solution is also possible:

```
return datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport).then(function () {
    if (idItin == -1) datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran);
    return datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. One question: how do you see that createItineraryDetailTransport don't return a promise? In this function the return statement is set on `manager.addEntity` and I thought this one returned a promise.

Comment: You can see here: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_addEntity. The 'addEntity' method returns the added entity not a promise.

Comment: Nearly good. I need to place the call to `createItineraryDetailTransport` between the 2 others call (and not the last call). So how to proceed to have this function to return a promise?

Comment: Mmmm I think of another problem: sometimes this function `createItineraryDetailTransport ` is never called because the condition (idItin == -1) is false. I try `.then(function () { if (idItin == -1) return datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran); else return; })` but it doesn't work. It seems in this case when (idItin==-1) the last call is never executed.

Comment: I have done a little moddification in the last code example. There was a return that it didn't have to be.